# Operator = problems to overload it

Tags: c++, operators

I want to overload the operator = for a class named Dictionary.With these atributes:

```
private:
char *language;
int noWords;
bool isOnline;
Word *v;
```

Word is another class with these atributes:

```
public:
char *value;
char type[20];
int noChars;
static int noWords;
```

This is how I want to overload the operator = for the class Dictionary:

```
void operator=(Dictionary x)
{
    this->language = new char[strlen(x.language)+1];
    strcpy(this->language,x.language);
    this->noWords = x.noWords;
    this->isOnline = x.isOnline;
    for (int i = 0; i < noWords; i++)
    {

        this->v[i].noChars = x.v[i].noChars;
        strcpy(this->v[i].type, x.v[i].type);
        this->v[i].value = new char[strlen(x.v[i].value) + 1];
        strcpy(this->v[i].value, x.v[i].value);

    }
}
```

I receive the error: "Acces violation writing location" and redirects me to this line:

```
this->v[i].noChars = x.v[i].noChars;
```

What should I change? I can't use strings. Just tell me what to modify with the same format.

P.S.: Can I do this in the default constructor:

```
        this->v = NULL;
```

?

Comment: Why are you using `char*` and `char` arrays instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @segevara That's not what access violation means. It's a runtime error.

Comment: @segevara - no, `operator=` is a member function (it's not written that way, but the language definition requires it to be one), so it has access to the private parts of the argument.

Comment: You need to allocate this->v before assigning to it.  (i.e. you are making a deep copy)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not allowed yet to use string....The teacher want use to understand pointers maybe....

Comment: @PeteBecker good to know tnx!

Comment: I added the default constructor and another one. Can you check for errors?

Comment: @CiobanuRares-Constantin Seriously, teachers who claim to be teaching C++ and 1) can't give you the canonical `operator= ` that an experienced programmer would use (it should return a reference to **this**), and 2) not tell you that a copy constructor should accompany the assignment operator, are doing you a disservice.  If you get a "A" grade for this, and then go out in the real world thinking this is the way things are done, well that is another disservice (if not you, then your fellow students who want to become C++ programmers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should consider using std::vector and std::string instead of allocating with new[] and managing the data directly.

Try this:

```
void clear()
{
    if( language )
    {
        delete[] language;
        language = 0;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < noWords; ++i )
        delete[] v[i].value; 
    delete[] v;
    v = 0;
}

void operator=(Dictionary x)
{
    // You really should deallocate any old value to avoid a memory leak
    clear();
    this->language = new char[strlen(x.language)+1];
    strcpy(this->language,x.language);
    this->noWords = x.noWords;
    this->isOnline = x.isOnline;
    this->v = new Word[noWords];
    for (int i = 0; i < noWords; i++)
    {
        this->v[i].noChars = x.v[i].noChars;
        strcpy(this->v[i].type, x.v[i].type);
        this->v[i].value = new char[strlen(x.v[i].value) + 1];
        strcpy(this->v[i].value, x.v[i].value);

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't :))) I wish too. Next week I will learn std::string for my final but std::string will represent 1/10 from the final grade :))

Comment: ~Dictionary()
 {
  if (v != NULL)
  {
   delete[] this->v;

  }
  if (language != NULL)
   delete[] this->language;
 }

Comment: Where I delete the memory. In the destructor at the line with this->v

Comment: After you delete, set it to nullptr.

Comment: Also if( v != NULL ) is the same as if( v )

Comment: I never used nullptr.  can you write the command please? I don't understand what you mean sorry.  About if(v) you are right :)))

Comment: If you are using C++ 11 or later, use nullptr instead of NULL because it is more type safe.  I added a clear function to illustrate clearing before the assignment.